# For which logic output of funcntion $\tau$ will be K logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic

We have

$ L = \{\land , \lor , \to , \bot , \lnot \} $

and

$L_\Box  = \{\land , \lor , \to , \bot , \lnot  ,\Box  \}$

and then we define function $\tau : L \to L_\Box$ like below

$\tau(p) = \Box p $

$\tau(\bot) = \bot $

$\tau(A \land B) = \tau(A) \land  \tau(B) $

$\tau(A \lor B) = \tau(A) \lor \tau(B) $

$\tau(A \to B) = \Box( \;\tau(A) \to  \tau(B)\;  )$

$\tau(\lnot A) =\Box\lnot\tau(A) $

then i know that

$\tau(cl)=S5$   which **cl** is **classical logic** and

$\tau(Il)=S4$   which **Il** is **intuitionistic logic** and

$\tau(Bl)=K4$   which **Bl** is **basic logic**

and i wanna know which weaker logic than basic logic should be the input of function that output be the **K** logic

$\tau(???)=K$